# MongoDB aggregate include pseudo data

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple aggregate that just returns the a sum of users by status between a certain time frame.

```
User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "created" : {
          $gt: startDate,
          $lt: endDate
       } 
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$status",
      "count" : {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

What I would like to do is display data for every day within the date range, even if there is no data.

So for example, the result may end up something like this:

```
[{
 '_id' : '01-15-2015',
  status_counts: {
    'active': 15,
    'inactive': 25,
    'removed': 2
  }
},
{
 '_id' : '01-16-2015',
  status_counts: {
    'active': 0,
    'inactive': 0,
    'removed': 0
  }
},
{
 '_id' : '01-17-2015',
  status_counts: {
    'active': 25,
    'inactive': 5,
    'removed': 1
  }
}]
```

Any ideas how I could go about doing this? Essentially summing all statuses and grouped by day, but if no data is there, include default data zeroed out?

Example Data:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55413bc29d41675785bf7ed2"),
    "status" : "active",
    "created" : ISODate("2015-10-11T17:25:46.843Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55413bc29d41675785bf7ed2"),
    "status" : "inactive",
    "created" : ISODate("2015-10-12T17:25:46.843Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55413bc29d41675785bf7ed2"),
    "status" : "removed",
    "created" : ISODate("2015-10-12T17:25:46.843Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55413bc29d41675785bf7ed2"),
    "status" : "active",
    "created" : ISODate("2015-10-14T17:25:46.843Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55413bc29d41675785bf7ed2"),
    "status" : "active",
    "created" : ISODate("2015-10-14T17:25:46.843Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55413bc29d41675785bf7ed2"),
    "status" : "active",
    "created" : ISODate("2015-10-17T17:25:46.843Z")
}]
```

Example Result:

```
[{
    "_id":"10-11-2015",
    "status_counts": {
        "active":1,
        "inactive":0,
        "removed":0
    }
},
{
    "_id":"10-12-2015",
    "status_counts": {
        "active":0,
        "inactive":1,
        "removed":1
    }
},
{
    "_id":"10-13-2015",
    "status_counts": {
        "active":0,
        "inactive":0,
        "removed":0
    }
},
{
    "_id":"10-14-2015",
    "status_counts": {
        "active":2,
        "inactive":0,
        "removed":0
    }
},
{
    "_id":"10-15-2015",
    "status_counts": {
        "active":0,
        "inactive":0,
        "removed":0
    }
},
{
    "_id":"10-16-2015",
    "status_counts": {
        "active":0,
        "inactive":0,
        "removed":0
    }
},
{
    "_id":"10-17-2015",
    "status_counts": {
        "active":1,
        "inactive":0,
        "removed":0
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following pipeline where pipeline where the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** stage creates a document with a new property that is composed only by the month-day-year by using the **[date aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/)** and the **[string operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#string-operators)** **[`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/#exp._S_concat)**, **[`$subtr`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/#exp._S_substr)** operators to do the string manipulation. You can then use the new property in the preceding **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step as the group key and obtain the respective status counts by using the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)** operator to evaluate the status type and assign the value to **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)**. The closing **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline stage then reshapes the final documents to provide the needed fields within a subdocument:

```
User.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "created": { "$gt": startDate, "$lt": endDate } 
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
           "_id": 0, "status": 1,
           "dayPart": {
                "$concat" : [ 
                    {
                        "$substr": [ {"$month" : "$created"}, 0, 2 ]
                    }, "-",
                    {
                        "$substr": [ {"$dayOfMonth" : "$created"}, 0, 2 ]
                    }, "-",
                    { 
                        "$substr": [ {"$year" : "$created"}, 0, 4 ]
                    }
                ] 
           }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": "$dayPart",             
            "active_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "active" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "inactive_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "inactive" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "removed_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "removed" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            }            
        }  
    },
    {
        "$project": {            
            "status_counts": {
                "active": "$active_count",
                "inactive": "$inactive_count",
                "removed": "$removed_count"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: This is awesome! One thing though, if it doesn't have any records for a day within the provided range, it doesn't return anything.  Anyway to include day's that don't have any data?

Comment: Thank you, just added some example data and an example result